# The rendering of language regex in a markdown code block is somewhat monotone

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167918/64348) to a question about regex's I put this language element in my markdown:

```
<!-- language: lang-regex -->

    [^;]+=(?<val>[^;]*)
```

This rendered as the crimson text we typically see as the default in Visual Studio for strings. I had expected something a bit more sensitive to regex's language elements (e.g. quantifiers, groupings, literals, etc.).

Are there any plans to change this or is there a different (better) language element that can be used?

Perhaps someone could contrib an update to the Google Prettyfier so SE can benefit?

Comment: So you'd say it looks somewhat ... regular? *yeah, I'll leave*

Comment: *Is there a different (better) language element that can be used?* Have you tried `lang-perl`?

Comment: Just did at your suggestion; does the same thing.

Comment: I believe this is handled by the [google-code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) script, so I'm not sure how much control SE has over it...

Comment: For the record, `lang-regex` _is_ a valid language selection according to [this MSE FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/213671).

Comment: I'm not sure this can be regarded as a bug, to me it seems more like a feature request or discussion

Comment: Hm true. Updated as a feature request.